# Why My broadcast receiver is not responding to any of the phone state?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

Actually, I want a broadcast receiver that can read the phone state like `calling`, `OFFHOOK`, `idle`.
here is my code.

I have added the `<uses-permission>` for reading Phone State in Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Here is my Statically registered Receiver

```
<receiver android:name=".CallStateBroadcast">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This is the MainActivity.Java

```
package com.example.callstateapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    CallStateBroadcast myReceiver = new CallStateBroadcast();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        registerReceiver(myReceiver,intentFilter);
    }
}
```

This is CallStateBroadcast.Class

```
package com.example.callstateapp;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CallStateBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
    Context mContext;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
            Toast.makeText(context, "Ringing...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK))
            Toast.makeText(context, "Busy...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE))
            Toast.makeText(context, "Free...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running it on API level > 20?

Comment: minSdkVersion 21
 targetSdkVersion 30

Comment: Actually, I m a beginner in android dev, so please guide me

Comment: You need to request runtime permission from the user, to see how it is implemented, check this link https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: yes buddy, what i did just for now, allowed the permissions from settings manually. but now I will add runtime permissions as per the documentation. thanks to your suggestion buddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register your receiver class at least once when your application starts. You can add this in your `MainActivity.java` file and it will work.

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    CallStateBroadcast myReceiver = new CallStateBroadcast();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
    registerReceiver(myReceiver,intentFilter);
}
```

**CallStateBroadcast.java**

```
public class CallStateBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
    Context mContext;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            Log.e("Zed", "ringing");
            Toast.makeText(context, "Ringing...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
            Log.e("Zed", "offhook");
            Toast.makeText(context, "Busy...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
            Log.e("Zed", "idle");
            Toast.makeText(context, "Free...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myapplication">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".CallStateBroadcast">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

**Edit**

I uploaded my sample project code for you to check. MinSdk version 21, TargetSdk 30.

Here is the recording of working. https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqqqO.gif

Comment: Zankrut Parmar, Thanks for your reply and suggestion but I have already register CallStateBroadcast in the Manifest File, and now also after your suggestion, I tried what you suggested, but still, it is not working.

Comment: I actually created a new project using your code and used my above code in `MainActivity.java` and it is working in latest build too. Can you tell me where you registered your broadcast intent in your activity file?

Comment: Also please make sure you allow the permission from settings app. Sometimes programmers forget to allow the permission from settings.

Comment: i just registered my receiver in the main activity as you told me to do so, and also provided the permission of phone call from settings, but still not working bTW your points are still very helpful to spacially that permission from settings one. thanks, buddy!

Comment: I don't know what is wrong then cause I used your code and it is working in my project as you can see.

Comment: it's working now (^_^), thank you so much, brother...

Comment: what I did just uninstalled the previous build version of code and reinstalled it again and then allowed the phone state permissions from the settings. BtW it's working fine now, now I have to add runtime permissions only to read the phone state in a user-friendly behaviour.

Comment: Glad to hear that. :D

Answer (score 0):

To use READ_PHONE_STATE you need:

```
Note: If both your minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion values are set to 3 or lower, the system implicitly grants your app this permission. If you don't need this permission, be sure your targetSdkVersion is 4 or higher.
```

Then, you need to specify:

```
<uses-sdk
 android:minSdkVersion="20"
 android:targetSdkVersion="whatyouwant" />
```